# SQL Server creating missing entries

Tags: sql-server

I would like to add missing sequence entries in temp table

```
Declare @tbl as  table
(
    orderid varchar(50),
    sequence int
)


insert into @tbl
select '1548756', 3
union
select '1878966',2

select * from @tbl
```

Current output:

```
1548756 3
1878966 2
```

I want to modified as below output add missing sequence in temp table:

```
1548756 3
1548756 2
1548756 1
1878966 2
1878966 1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please format the question properly so that it becomes more readable? Also the problem statement is not clear about what feature you want implement. Provide the code which you have written implement this and tell us where is it not working properly or what error you are facing.

Comment: Do you want to insert missing data into your table.or else you just want to show them in the  output itself .??

Comment: Define "missing"! If you only insert 2 rows, there is nothing missing if only 2 rows are returned.

Comment: Thanks but i think tanner below sql statement fix my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a recursive cte using your initial rows as the anchor point and the subtract 1 from the sequence on each recursion until the value is 1:

```
DECLARE @tbl AS  TABLE
    (
      orderid VARCHAR(50) ,
      sequence INT
    );


INSERT  INTO @tbl
        SELECT  '1548756' ,
                3
        UNION
        SELECT  '1878966' ,
                2;

SELECT  *
FROM    @tbl;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   orderid ,
                        sequence
               FROM     @tbl
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   cte.orderid ,
                        CASE WHEN cte.sequence > 1 THEN cte.sequence - 1
                        END AS sequence
               FROM     cte
                        INNER JOIN @tbl t ON t.orderid = cte.orderid
               WHERE    cte.sequence > 1
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY orderid ,
            sequence desc
```

Gives you:

```
orderid sequence
1548756 3
1548756 2
1548756 1
1878966 2
1878966 1
```

Comment: Thanks Tanner that's help a lot